# List files in directory C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
to create a program which will list all filenames in a directory in a `Windows::Forms::ListBox`.

Since the user won't be doing any inputting I won't be needing the
`void DisplayErrorBox(LPTSTR lpszFunction)` function along with other error checking.

When I click the button that triggers the event this is what is shown in the list box.

```
o //&#o/
/ //
/ //
/ //
/ //
/ //
/ //
/ //
```

Also, only one row appear each time i click the button.
It's supposed to find all the files in the directory and list them not just find the next file each time I click the button.

I also want to use a relative strPath, not absolute...
So far this is what I've done with the code:

```
private:
    void List_Files()
    {
        std::string strPath =   "C:\\Users\\Andre\\Dropbox\\Programmering privat\\Diablo III DPS Calculator\\Debug\\SavedProfiles";     
        TCHAR* Path = (TCHAR*)strPath.c_str();

        WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
        LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
        TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
        size_t length_of_arg;
        HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

        // Prepare string for use with FindFile functions.  First, copy the
        // string to a buffer, then append '\*' to the directory name.

        StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, Path);
        StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));

        // List all the files in the directory with some info about them.

        do
        {
          if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
          {
              //If it's a directory nothing should happen. Just continue with the next file.

          }
          else
          {
                //convert from wide char to narrow char array
                char ch[260];
                char DefChar = ' ';

                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,(ffd.cFileName),-1, ch,260,&DefChar, NULL);

                //A std:string  using the char* constructor.
                std::string str(ch);
                String ^ sysStr = gcnew String(str.c_str());

              MessageBox::Show("File Found", "NOTE");
              ListBoxSavedFiles->Items->Add (sysStr);

          }
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        FindClose(hFind);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use so many string types: std::string, System::String, Wide-char strings, char-strings ??

Comment: So, use .NET framework to retrieve the list!

Comment: @Ajay
I need to use System::String beacuse i'm working with System::Windows::Forms and the std::string i need because some functions won't take the System::string.

but when it comes to the wide char string and char string
and the `WideCharToMultiByte` function, I googeled that part to convert from ffd.cFileName to a string i could use.
so if there's a better way to do it i would gladly try it.

Comment: Not sure how to use the .NET framework.
i'll google a bit and see if i can find something useful.

Comment: Use TCHAR, or use ANSI build. See this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FindFirstFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is never called, you need to call it before calling `FindNextFile()`:

```
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Andre\\Dropbox\\Programmering privat\\Diablo III DPS Calculator\\Debug\\SavedProfiles\\*"), &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFind)
{
    do
    {
        //...

    } while(FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    FindClose(hFind);
}
else
{
    // Report failure.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), you can use a [`directory_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator):

```
using boost::filesystem;

path p("some_dir");
for (directory_iterator it(p); it != directory_iterator(); ++it) {
    cout << it->path() << endl;
}
```

It works on Windows too and it definitely looks much simpler. Of course, you would need to adapt your current code a little bit, but I think in the long term it is well worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

The cast `(TCHAR*)strPath.c_str();` is wrong. From your use of `WideCharToMultiByte` I know that `(TCHAR*)strPath.c_str();` is casting a `char const*`  to a `wchar_t*`. Not only does that lose a  `const`, but the width is also wrong.

Comment: Although you're identifying a problem with the code there, that doesn't help the OP with solving the problem. All the different String types in C++ can be very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Visual Studio then change the configuration settings to `Use Multibyte Character set`. This will your TCHAR thing to compile without any cast.